# The columns containing relative abundance taxa does not sum to 1 in R but the same data does in excel

Tags: r, rounding, frequency, numeric, calculated-columns

I have a data file with 95 columns and many rows (over 14000). I have calculated the relative abundance and now want to verify that sum of each column is 1. But it does not work on R. I tried to test if sum of each column is real 1 (or near 1) and did it manually in excel and it did, the sum of columns was 1. I tried to change the tolerance if the issue is because of rounding numbers, but it was not. here is my code:

```
tolerance <- 1e-10
sums_relative_abundance <- colSums(relative_abundances)
all(abs(sums_relative_abundance - 1.0) < tolerance)
```

my data has 95 columns.

```
head(relative_abundances)
 

     X1003           X1004           X1027           X1049
1   2.334938e-03    8.367276e-04    8.928571e-03    3.050125e-02    
2   2.880184e-04    1.224950e-04    6.647746e-04    3.065996e-04    
3   1.457391e-03    7.153990e-04    1.106922e-03    5.461621e-04    
4   5.188696e-05    3.413513e-05    8.658196e-05    1.800099e-05    
5   2.164549e-05    9.000495e-06    1.882176e-05    9.798542e-06    
6   1.882176e-05    1.959708e-05    5.381118e-05    1.104796e-04    

dput(head(sums_relative_abundance))
c(X1003 = 0.523067970544805, X1004 = 0.462073648305777, X1027 = 0.751016736292847, 
X1049 = 1.14795999147871, X1053 = 0.892912676398911, X1058 = 1.03526073508692
)
```

Comment: What is `relative_abundances`? Your data frame? Are all columns relevant for your calculation? Remove `all` and check if there are some `TRUE` values. Perhaps, `1e-10` too small?

Comment: Thank you for replay, yes it is my data frame and all columns contain relative freq. And sum of each column should be 1 (or near1). I changed the tolerance and also removed all, but still not working.

Comment: Please share a few lines. For example, the first values of `colSums(relative_abundances)` as text: `dput(head(sums_relative_abundance))`.

Comment: I shared the data dput(head(sums_relative_abundance)) and head(relative_abundances)

Comment: What is your approach in Excel? Are you confusing rowSums and colSums?

Comment: I check it on excel to see if there the sum of data in each column is realy 1 and if there is no problem with my data, and when i sum each column in excel, the result is 1 for each column but here in R it’s different result for the same data.

Comment: Also check the number of records and min/max match Excel.  Are you pulling the data into R directly from Excel?

Comment: The data is in a txt file and I exported the data as excel only to chekck/verfiy manually that the data is correct and the sum of each column is 1.